# Calculating Expected Value Involving Combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that a child desires $5$ different toys for her birthday. Ten people will come to her birthday party, each of them equally likely to bring any one of the $5$ toys. Let $X$ be the number of different types of toys brought to the party.

I am asked to calculate $E[x]$. With my understanding of $E[x]$, I am basically computing $E[X]$ = (1)P(1 toy type) + (2)P(2 toy types) + (3)P(3 toy types) + (4)P(4 toy types) + (5)P(5 toy types).

I know that the total number of ways that ten people can bring the $5$ toys is $\binom{10+5-1}{5}$. The number of ways where only $1$ type is $\binom{5}{1}\binom{10+1-1}{10}$. This makes P(1 toy type) = $\frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{10+1-1}{10}}{\binom{10+5-1}{5}}$

Is this general train of reasoning correct?

Comment: I think it's easier to use Linearity of Expectation.  Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ toy (so it is $1$ iff that toy is brought to the party).  What is $E[X_i]$?

Comment: Would $E[X_i]$ just be equal to the probability of the $i^th$ toy being brought would be $\frac{\binom{9+5-1}{9}}{\binom{10+5-1}{5}}$? Doesn't this mean that $E[x] = 5E[X_i]$?

Comment: The probability that the $i^{th}$ toy is brought is $1$ minus the probability that it isn't, hence $1-\left( \frac 45\right)^{10}$.  And then, yes, $E[X]=5E[X_i]$.